# Is there a Github Merge message template

Tags: github, merge, automation, pull-request

[GitHub Merge message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik3mG.png)

Every time you want to merge a pull request manually, there is the option to manually write a merge message with title and text.

Is there any option to create a template or automatically change the title of the merge message?

Comment: Join the party https://github.com/community/community/discussions/5955